# How to set default Start screen layout?

Tags: windows-8, start-screen

I've seen some OEMs install custom apps and add them to the start screen layout. Does putting the `appsfolder.itemdata-ms` in the `C:\Users\Default\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows` folder work? I want to know if this will delete the file after using `sysprep` `/oobe` `/generalize`.

Comment: To answer the last sentence, `SysPrep` will wipe changes to `%AppData%`/`%LocalAppData%` since `SysPrep` removes local users when generalizing _(unsure if the same when `generalize` is not chosen)_. OOBE shouldn't remove existing user profiles that have been configured, as it simply restarts Windows Setup phase 7 [`oobeSystem`] _(Windows Setup has [7 phases](https://superuser.com/a/1699572/529800), including `generalize`, which occurs from WinPE, whereas `oobeSystem` occurs while booted to the OS)_

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found [this article on the Internet](http://chentiangemalc.wordpress.com/2011/11/02/customizing-default-start-menu-in-windows-developer-preview/) about customizing the default start menu.

Comment: Links should be supplemental. Answers should be written so that a broken link won't render them useless.