# Apply autounattend.xml after deploying image with Dism

Tags: windows, xml, dism

I am looking for a way to apply an `autounattend.xml`/`unattend.xml` after the image has been deployed with `Dism` to bypass OOBE:

- I have deployed a Windows image with `Dism`, adding the `autoattend.xml` to `Windows\Panther`, as well as `Windows/System32/sysprep`, but neither of these worked
- If I make a bootable USB and paste the `autounattend.xml` in the USB's root before installation, it works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't, as the [`unattend.xml`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/update-windows-settings-and-scripts-create-your-own-answer-file-sxs) is used by [Windows Setup](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/windows-setup-automation-overview), not `Dism`:

- Windows is installed in [seven phases](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/how-configuration-passes-work) *(incl. [`generalize`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/generalize))*, with the answer file being applied to the offline image during `offlineServicing` and `specialize`, which occurs before `auditSystem`, `auditUser`, and `oobeSystem`:

  - Upon selecting *Install*: [`windowsPE`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/windowspe)
  - Setup boots to WinPE: [`offlineServicing`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/offlineservicing), [`specialize`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/specialize)
  - Setup boots to applied image: [`auditSystem`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/auditsystem), [`auditUser`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/audituser), [`oobeSystem`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/oobesystem)

What you're attempting to do is called an [LTI](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/mem/configmgr/mdt/lite-touch-installation-guide)/[ZTI](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/mem/configmgr/mdt/configmgr-guide) [**L**ite/**Z**ero **T**ouch **I**nstall]:

1. [Mount](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/windows-setup-automation-overview#replace-the-answer-file-in-an-offline-image) the WinPE `boot.wim` → Copy `unatennd.xml` to `Windows\Panther` → Unmount image
2. Boot the `boot.wim` either:

   - via external media [USB]
   - by [creating](https://superuser.com/a/1698320/529800) a WinPE boot partition on the HDD

     ```bsh
     MakeWinPEMedia /Ufd "C:\WinPE\MountDirectory" F:
     ```

     - *[configure](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/customize/desktop/wsim/create-or-open-an-answer-file) the removal of this partition in the answer file during `auditSystem` 
        <sup>(possibly during `oobeSystem`, but I can't recall)</sup>*